# How to add npm package to my Vite + React app?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm making a project that uses Vite + React (I use vanilla jsx) and I want to use a npm package (react-new-window to be specific) but I can't find how.

I look up on Google but can't see any step-by-step tutorial that I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that package's npm page? anyway did you try `npm i react-new-window --save`

Comment: I've just run the command, what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package by

npm install react-new-window

After Installation you can read the documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-new-window